# Can this July 1958 NYC baseball game be identified?

Tags: baseball, history, match-identification

I've got two photos of a night game in NYC area after July 4, 1958 and before the end of August 1958 (when film was developed), likely around July 5 or 6.

Can anyone identify:

- The Stadium
- The Home Team
- The Visiting Team
- The likely game date
- Any other info, such as current players on field

[image]

Detail of pitcher and batter/catcher:

[image][image]

[image]

Detail of pitcher and batter/catcher:

[image][image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because memorabilia identification questions are not suitable for Sports Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Nij Can you please suggest a better site at StackExchange for it?

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: Without doing too much research, I could tell you it's likely held at the old Yankees stadium based on [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yankee_Stadium_(1923)#/media/File:Yankee_Stadium_Color_1959.jpg) from Wikipedia's page on the old stadium. Compare the white railing on the second deck on each picture.  With that, it's safe to assume the home team is the Yankees. They had 5 opponent's at home after July 4th so it could be any of the [five teams](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/1958-schedule-scores.shtml) as the opponent.

Comment: Very well could be the Red Sox based on the... red socks.

Comment: @Steve-o169 That looks like an answer to me...

Comment: @WilliamKF Probably right, but I'm assuming this will be closed as off-topic so just gave some details in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put this up as an answer because this question seems like it might not get closed...

From the description as being "in the NYC area", it was a quick leap to assume that we're talking about the Yankees here.  The time frame(1958) makes them the only likely choice given that the New York Mets did not exist and the [New York Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_New_York_Giants_(baseball)) moved to San Francisco after the 1957 season.

This basically leaves only the Yankees in NYC and they played in the [old Yankee Stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yankee_Stadium_(1923)) from 1923 through 2008.  From the Wikipedia page for the old Yankee Stadium, I found this picture, which shows a similar white railing in the second deck along the first base line.  This and other features seem to match up with the pictures presented.

[image]

With the home team and location seemingly confirmed, looking at the [Yankees schedule from 1958](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/1958-schedule-scores.shtml) shows a home stand from July 5th through the 20th including a 2-game series against the Red Sox,  a 5-game series against Cleveland, 3-game series' against the White Sox and Tigers, and a 4-game series against the Kansas City Athletics.  Based on [the uniforms](http://exhibits.baseballhalloffame.org/dressed_to_the_nines/detail_page.asp?Entryid=922&fileName=al_1958_boston.gif) worn by the Red Sox during that season and the red stripe on the socks, it is probable that the Red Sox are the opponent in this game.  These games were played July 5th and 6th.

The [Red Sox roster](http://baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1958-roster.shtml) included a 39-year-old Ted Williams and the [Yankees roster](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/1958-roster.shtml) included the likes of Yogi Berra, Mickey Mantle, and Whitey Ford.  The best I can tell, the Yankees batter is wearing number 7 which would, in fact, be the [number that Mickey Mantle wore](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/1958-uniform-numbers.shtml) that year. If the opponent is the Red Sox, the batter is either wearing 8 or 9 but the number is obscured by the bat being swung.  Number 8 is Pete Daley and [number 9 would be Ted Williams](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1958-uniform-numbers.shtml).  Additional analysis would show that Pete Daley was a right-handed hitter -- which would mean this is most likely Ted Williams, who was a left-handed batter.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks!  I'd say Ted Williams is most likely since the choice was made to only take two photographs during the game.

Comment: @WilliamKF Looks like we can actually eliminate Pete Daley as he was a right-handed batter.  I'll add that to the answer, but it's most probably Ted Williams based on that.

Comment: @WilliamKF I have a feeling it relates to [this meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/generalising-the-off-topicality-of-autograph-identification-questions).  No worries, in my opinion it was a specific and well presented question that gave enough details to answer it with reasonable certainty.  I understand the issue with most autograph/memorabilia questions, but this didn't fit the mold.